# set permission to role spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-permission

I'm trying to use this library and set permission to my users. I'm reading documentation and I created my roles. I set my array in input with name.

```
@foreach ($allPermission as $permission)
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <label class="form-check-label mr-4" for="{{ $permission->id }}">{{ $permission->name }}</label>
                      <input class="form-check-input" name="permission[]" type="checkbox" id="{{ $permission->id }}" value="{{ $permission->name }}">
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
```

In my controller, I received this:

```
Array ( [0] => show [1] => create [2] => destroy )
```

I'm trying to set this permissions with this:

```
$user = User::where("id", $id)->update([
                                    'name'      => $request->get('name'),
                                    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
                                    'password'  => \Hash::make($request->get('password')),
                                ]);
            
            // update permissions to user
            $user->givePermissionTo($request->get('permission'));
```

this returns...

```
Call to a member function givePermissionTo() on int
```

I'm trying to set permissions with id and with name and getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = User::where("id", $id)->update([
                                    'name'      => $request->get('name'),
                                    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
                                    'password'  => \Hash::make($request->get('password')),
                                ]);
```

return `$user` is `count records` was updated (`$user` of you is not a collection)

you can use :

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

then

```
$user->givePermissionTo($request->get('permission'));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i don´t need this. I need apply permissions to user, my user it´s updated correctly

Comment: `$user` of you return 1 and  `$user->givePermissionTo($request->get('permission'));` get error. You need get a collection